# A word for: Taking a godlike concept and bringing it down to earth

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

There is this beautiful woman I always wanted, and who looked so beautiful and pure, like a goddess, and then we dated and she lost all this glory and she became just another girl.

What do you call the process that my concept of her went through?

Share your most beautiful words!

Comment: Here I thought you were looking for the opposite of *apotheosis*.

Comment: You had a [reality check](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=reality+check&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=e8zGT8bRO8is0QWBpOyNCw&ved=0CGEQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=992e3404e3e1c054&biw=1155&bih=824)

Comment: "There are only two types of women: goddesses and doormats." -- Picasso

Comment: Kind of the opposite of `apotheosis`?

Comment: I've been through this with a woman also. But better to have dated and "lost" than not at all. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54487/how-did-the-term-mistress-take-on-two-rather-different-connotations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At their root, *disillusion* and *disenchant* capture this process perfectly:

> **disillusion**, *tr.v.* : to free from or deprive of illusion
>
> **disenchant**, *tr.v.* : to free from enchantment

Comment: One could add [_disenamored_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disenamor) to the list as well.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of idioms came to mind:

You could say when you were pining for her that you [*put her on a pedestal*,](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+a+pedestal) but familiarity knocked her off.

You could also say that [*familiarity bred contempt*.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Familiarity+breeds+contempt)

Answer (score 1):

*Disabused* could also fit here, assuming that the reality was corrective of an erroneous first impression or judgment.

Answer (score 1):

A descriptive word might be **undeified,** as in you "undeified" her.